# Html has java Script in it. How to extract HTML tags from it

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have to download all html of the URL link. But I'm not getting any HTML tags. Instead I got only these lines.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head><meta charset="utf-8">  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    <title></title>
 <link href="/github-user-search/app.bundle.562f293b75a96de878ab.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body>
 <div id="root"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/github-user-search/app.bundle.562f293b75a96de878ab.js"></script></body>
 </html>
```

```py
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url ='https://simonsmith.github.io/github-user-search/#/search?per_page=42&page=1&q=Ben%20Newman'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
soup.findAll('a')
```

Comment: what are you actually after from that page? Is it really just all the html?

Answer (score 0):

When you make the request to the above url, the content is loaded asynchronously by javascript, so when you use the content, you wont be able to **scrape** the contents loaded asynchronously
You need to wait for the content to load before parsing,
i would recommend using phantom js / puppeteer to wait for the dynamic content to load and then scrape, wait till the content loads by using the jquery like the one below ,which waits till the user details are loaded on the page, and then proceed with data extraction

```
$('*[class^="User_"]')
```